# Timeouts for individual UDP sockets in C

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, udp, timeout

I have a bunch of UDP sockets that I need to read/write data to. I'm using `select` to loop over the sockets to determine read/write readiness. So unless a socket is ready, I never use `recvfrom` or `sendto` on them, because I don't want my program to block.

My problem is, I need to implement a timeout on a socket if I haven't been able to read from it in a while.

So far, I've seen many suggestions, such as:

1. Putting a timeout on `select`: However, this wouldn't work if `n-1` sockets are always ready, but the `n`th socket never receives data; `select` would never timeout. I want a timeout particularly for the `n`th socket.
2. Use `setsockopt` : However, this requires that I block at the `recvfrom` call, which I can't afford as I have to attend to other sockets if they are ready.

I need a way for my program to signal a timeout if a socket hasn't been ready to `recvfrom` for some time. Note that I cannot afford to block, nor can I use threads or  forking.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "*So unless a socket is ready, I never use recvfrom or sendto on them, because I don't want my program to block.*" That doesn't work. You have to set the socket non-blocking to ensure an operation won't block. That the socket *was* ready before does not provide any future guarantee that a subsequent operation won't block and there can be very surprising ways a socket can become "unready". (For example, if checksum checking was off when you detected readiness and then was turned on before you called `recvfrom`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `select()` you have to keep track of the last time a socket was readable, and process the set of sockets that *weren't* readable at the end of each `select()` loop, comparing against their last-readable time. Just a simple data structure problem.

Comment: Thanks! I just have a question about this method:  what if I have a lot of sockets and the first socket were to become ready just as I hit the end of my `select()` loop? As in, wouldn't looping through my other sockets interfere with timeout calculations?

Comment: If the socket has already timed out, the fact that it has subseqently become ready is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

For UDP, you should know that the socket_fd will always writable(Actually udp don't have send buffer so I say this. Platform:Linux). So that if you put a timeout on `select()`, you'll almost always get the `select` return sockets which are writable. You could check whether it's writable or readable.

A simple method is when you find the select return sockets, check whether readable sockets first. If no and you don't have any date to send, sleep a while then loop again.

Comment: Sockets are mostly but not always writable. If the send buffer is full, the socket is not writable. `select()` does not return 1 or 2 according as sockets are ready to read or write: it returns the number of ready sockets, or zero, or -1 on an error. Calling `sendto()` does not involve a timeout on most platforms, and in any case the OP wants a *read* timeout.

Comment: Actually udp don't have socket buffer. If you call `sendto` to write data to a udp socket, it will copy to the network directly. For 1 and 2, I assume that the select only operate 1 socket. The assumption is not correct. I'll edit my answer.